# I think I have an error in Google Apps Script code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets, and attempting to create a menu that will allow me to run  my choice of several scripts, I'm doing something wrong and not quite sure what, could someone read over this and let me know what appears to be wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Menu');
 menu.addItem('Compare sheets', 'compare');
 menu.addItem('Clear Formats', 'clear');
 menu.addToUi();
}

function compare() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
        master = ss.getSheetByName('NewData'),
        newData = ss.getSheetByName('Master'),
        dif = ss.getSheetByName('Comparison'),
        rows = 500,
        columns = 52,
        bg = [],
        dateCols = [14, 24, 29, 36, 37],
        masterDataRange = master.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns),
        masterValues = masterDataRange.getValues(),
        newDataValues = newData.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns)
            .getValues();
    dif.getDataRange()
        .clear()
        .setBackground('White');
    for (var i = 0, rl = masterValues.length; i < rl; i++) {
        var r = [];
        for (var j = 0, cl = masterValues[0].length; j < cl; j++) {
            if (dateCols.indexOf(j) > -1 && i > 1) {
                if (masterValues[i][j] ) masterValues[i][j] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(masterValues[i][j]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
                if (newDataValues[i][j] ) newDataValues[i][j] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(newDataValues[i][j]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");              
            }
            r.push(i < 2 ? "white" : masterValues[i][j] !== newDataValues[i][j] ? "green" : "white");
            }
         bg.push(r);
        }
    dif.getRange(1, 1, masterValues.length, masterValues[0].length)
        .setValues(masterValues)
        .setBackgrounds(bg);
}

function clear(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
 first.clearFormats();
 }
```

Comment: We have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: You can know whether there is an error or not by looking in the Execution Transcript.  In the VIEW menu, choose Execution Transcript.  It will tell you what line the error is on, and give an error message.  The troubleshooting guide is very helpful:  [Link to Google Documentation - troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: The title of your question will not help anyone else looking for answers.  Consider changing the title to what the error message is, or deleting the question.

Comment: There was not an error in the execution script. It executes successfully. I'll adjust the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `DocumentApp` in a spreadsheet, you should use `SpreadsheetApp` instead !

**code :**

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Menu');
 menu.addItem('Compare sheets', 'compare');
 menu.addItem('Clear Formats', 'clear');
 menu.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I know these kinds of questions are annoying but I honestly am so new, I would have missed it for hours, thanks so much.